# VS code Tensorflow error: disable_resource_variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, tflearn

i was trying to make a simple chatbot in Python. But when I try to run my script, I get this error.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\compat\v2_compat.py:107: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
    from .recurrent import lstm, gru, simple_rnn, bidirectional_rnn, \
    from .recurrent import lstm, gru, simple_rnn, bidirectional_rnn, \
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tflearn\layers\recurrent.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util.nest import is_sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_sequence' from 'tensorflow.python.util.nest' (C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py)
```

```
python version is 3.11.3
Tensorflow version 2.13
```

Any idea what's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to tflearn. Here's the Github link about [Replaces is_sequence() with is_sequence_or_composite()](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/pull/1173/commits).

For me, I am currently using **tensorflow 2.12.0**, which can run correctly. You can try to downgrade TensorFlow.

Comment: Hi @MingJie-MSFT,

I tried downgrading to TensorFlow 2.12.0, but that didn't resolve the problem. Eventually, I decided to reinstall TensorFlow, tflearn, and Python but now  I'm facing a new error

```Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\oussa\OneDrive\Desktop\Folder\ChatBot\main.py", line 6, in <module>

import tflearn

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
```

Comment: ModuleNotFound was caused by incorrect python interpreter usually. You can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and choose the interpreter which you installed the package in.